# How do I set default value to today for Date Picker in VBA-Excel

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, userform

I am creating a user form with a date picker. I am trying to set the value to display as today's date instead of a generic date. I've tried to put formulas and set variables to add to the field however it's not working. I'm not sure how to adjust it to open to display today's date automatically instead of manually having to adjust it.

I have another field that I need to set to Blank as default as well but I'm also not sure how to do this.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you would need to add some code to your userform, something like that :)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
 TextBox1.Text = Format(Now(), "DD/MM/YYYY")
End Sub
```